# image does not save in the database in PHP

Tags: php, mysqli, file-upload

After user log into his profile I am showing his user profile. And there I let him to add his profile picture. After user add his profile picture I want to  insert image path to the database.

**database at the login**-id, username, password, email

**database after profile picture save** - id, username,password,email,name1(where img path save)

Following code save the picture in the given folder but it does not save the image path in the database.**can anybody help me please?**

```
<?php include('header.php');?>
<?php include('config.php');?>
<?php
    // index.php
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['username']))

     {
        header("Location: login.php");
    }
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $sql = "SELECT *  FROM services WHERE user_name = '".$_SESSION['username']."'";
    $result = $con->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        ?>
    <?php

    if(isset($_POST['but_upload'])){

     $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $target_dir = "upload/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);

    // Select file type
    $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

    // Valid file extensions
    $extensions_arr = array("jpg","jpeg","png","gif");

    // Check extension
    if( in_array($imageFileType,$extensions_arr) ){

  // Insert record
  //$query = "insert into services(name1) values('".$name."') where user_name = '".$_SESSION['username']."'";
  $query = " UPDATE services SET name1='$name' where user_name = '".$_SESSION['username']."";
  mysqli_query($con,$query);

  // Upload file
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$target_dir.$name);

 }

}
?>




<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-7 ">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading"> <center> <h4 >User Profile</h4></center></div>
                    <div class="panel-body">

                        <div class="box box-info">

                            <div class="box-body">
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <div  align="center"> 
                                    <form method="post" action="welcome.php" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
                                            <div class="imageupload panel panel-default">

                                                <div class="file-tab panel-body">
                                                    <label class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                                                    <span>Browse</span>
                        <!-- The file is stored here. -->
                                                    <input type="file" name="file">
                                                    </label>
                                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Remove</button>
                                                </div>
                                    <input type='submit' value='Save name' name='but_upload'>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>

              <br>

              <!-- /input-group -->
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h4 style="color:#00b1b1;"><?php echo $row ['name']; ?></h4></span>
              <span><p><?php echo $row ['service']; ?></p></span>            
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <hr style="margin:5px 0 5px 0;">
```

Comment: _"but it does not save the image path in the database"_ so what **does** it do?

Comment: hey, echo your $name and update $query and paste here

Comment: @Phil it saves the image in the given folder

Comment: It's probably because your query is failing due to the missing `'` at the end. You would know this if you checked the return value of `mysqli_query($con,$query)`. You would avoid this issue (and others) entirely if you used [prepared statements with bound parameters](http://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: Queries are not secure.  Use prepared statements with placeholders and binding. And I'd like to see the session start before the includes.  You don't need to check num_rows if you are calling a while loop.

Comment: Voting to close as a _typo_

Comment: Extra advice... your code continues to execute **after** `header("Location: login.php");`. **ALWAYS** `exit;` after issuing a redirect. See [Well-Intentioned Destruction](https://thedailywtf.com/articles/WellIntentioned-Destruction) for a cautionary tale

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change

```
$query = " UPDATE services SET name1='$name' where user_name = '".$_SESSION['username']."";
```

to

```
 $query = ("UPDATE services SET name1='$name' where user_name = '".$_SESSION['username']."") or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

I added `mysqli_error`. It will print errors in the query & brackets

Comment: @Lanka thank you very much now it displays this **Undefined variable: name**

Comment: If my answer solve your question, kindly mark my answer as accepted solution. Thank you @sadee

Comment: It means there is nothing in the `$name` variable.

Comment: @Lanka I did.You from Sri Lanka right? I don't know why other's always get negative scores once we ask something we don't know

Comment: @sadee - Yes I am from Sri Lanka. I also cant realize why the people are down voting our answers without any reason.

Comment: @Lanka.. me as well.. we post a question after trying and being tired